# Background-image: Using a link to an external resource within a div

Tags: html, image, url, background, background-image

I want to link an image url to a div so that image will be used as a background and watermark for the content within the div.

When I set the url to the body, it repeats the image, which i dont want.

```
<body style="background-color: white; background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/ntRarR/watermark3.png);">
...
</body>
```

And when I set the url within the div (where i want it and which is inside the body tag), the image does not appear.

```
<div style="background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/ntRarR/watermark3.png); text-align: center">
...
</div>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this way for image opacity

```css
.bgdiv {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width:450px;
    height:450px;
}

.bgdiv .bg {
    position: absolute;   
    background: url(https://preview.ibb.co/ntRarR/watermark3.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100%;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgdiv">
    <div class="bg"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

for body use

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;
```

```css
body{
background-image: url(https://preview.ibb.co/ntRarR/watermark3.png); text-align: center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;}
```

Comment: Great! I also wanted to set an opacity to this specific image.  How can i do that without having the entire body affected? @HirenPatel

Comment: i added opacity,check that

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your div is not empty.
- Use property 
  **background**:url('https://preview.ibb.co/ntRarR/watermark3.png');
  to give background for your div.
- If you apply background property to body tag, it will be applied to the 
   entire webpage.
- In case you want to apply background image to the body tag, use 
  **background-size**: cover; (cover the entire page).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help!